# Recommend Shopify Products Based on keywords

Tags: nlp, nltk, amazon-comprehend, google-language-api

i have some keywords e.g *["i have curly hairs", "24 years of age", "i have dry scalp", "i have frequent dandruff"]*.

Based on these keywords i want to suggest shopify products.Currently i can think of comparing shopify products descriptions, titles, meta-descriptions or tags with these keywords.
But how can i acheive this through nlp or nltk library.
Any concept or working example will be appreciated.

Comment: Look for basic tutorials on NLU and recommender systems, with code. There are loads out there.

Comment: yeah any tools or packages for easy handling of this?

Comment: Shaheer: welcome to SO! However [questions asking for recommendations are offtopic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). But like I said just google or search SO, YouTube, ML sites, Kaggle etc. for NLU (Natural Language Understanding) and recommender systems and you'll find tons of useful stuff. You can also specify e.g. *"with python, sklearn, nltk, pandas..."* in your search. Also try the sister site [DataScience.SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/search?q=NLU), if your question was more specific and had code it could be on-topic there.